# What can we tell about the difference between two eigenvalues in symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, svd

I am reading a lectre notes of Power method. You can find the notes [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos521/lecnotes/lec14.pdf)

> For a symmetric matrices $M$, pick a randomm unit vector $x$. If we
> write $x$ as $\sum_ia_ie_i$, where $e_i$ is eigenvectors and
> $\lambda_i$'s are numbered in decreasing  order by absolute value.
> Then $t$ iteration produce $M^tx=\sum_ia_i\lambda^t_ie_i$. Since $x$
> is a unit vector, $\sum_i a^2_i=1$. Suppose there is a *gap* of
> $\gamma$ between the top two eigenvalues:
> $\lambda_1-\lambda_2=\gamma$. Since $|\gamma_i|\leq|a_1|-\gamma$ for
> $i\geq2$, we have:  $\sum_{i\geq2}|a_i^t|\leq n(a_1-\gamma)^t=n|a_1|^t(1-\gamma/|a_1|)^t$

I don't understand how can we  derive the condition $|\gamma_i|\leq|a_1|-\gamma$

Comment: What is the definition of $\gamma_i$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis The notes didn't specify it, but I guess $\gamma_i$ will be the difference between adjacent eigenvalues. i.e. $\gamma_1 = \lambda_1-\lambda_2$